# Collapsing Bootstrap Navbar On Col-Sm

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to using Bootstrap and on my webpage I have a collapsable navbar. The problem is on my phone(Galaxy s6) It displays the col-sm an does not collapse the navbar into the button. Is there anyway to get the navbar to collapse at col-sm? Or is there a way to know if a device is mobile and display a certain way?

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S6 has a high-res screen, and so it manages to display the full nav.

You can use the visible-sm or hidden-sm(or hidden-xs/-md/-lg) classes to make sure some things only show on mobile(or only hide, if you use hidden-xs).